# Is there a way to programmatically switch accounts on metamask using web3?

Tags: metamask, decentralized-applications

I'm trying to add a utility to my dApp where the user doesn't need to access their metamask extension to switch accounts. Is it possible to integrate this?

For example, I would like my user to click on a button and it shall call a method, say `switchAccount(address)` and it will switch the account to this particular `address` I just mentioned.

As far as I have researched, this isn't possible "yet". But I just want to make sure this is correct.